# Dyck path - Probability of stopping time $2n$

Tags: markov-chains, catalan-numbers

Can someone explain to me, why the probability of returning to the origin of a Dyck path with length $2n$ is:

$\mathbb{P}(\tau=2n) = 2C_{n-1}4^{-n}$?

$C_n$ stands for the Catalan number and $\tau :=$inf$\{n\geq1:S_n=0\}$ is the distribution of the first entry time/ stopping time.

This is an example of a Dyck path:
[image: Dyck path]

Comment: What is your definition of *Dyck path*?

Comment: Dyck path is an one dimensional random walk from $0$ to $2n$ with beginning and ending in $0$, so the path is always above the x-axis.

Comment: If it’s a **one**-dimensional random walk, what do you mean by *above the* $x$-*axis*?

Comment: The path is never under the x-axis.

Comment: You’re missing my point. If the path is **one-dimensional**, I assume that it is along the $x$-axis, in which case it never goes above or below the $x$-axis. If it is not along the $x$-axis, where is it?

Comment: Sorry, but this is written in my notes. What should be correct is that the path never goes below the x-axis.

Comment: As it’s stated, it simply doesn’t make sense. I’m going to guess that we’re talking about paths that start at $\langle 0,0\rangle$ in the plane and take $2n$ steps, each of which is $\langle 1,1\rangle$ or $\langle 1,-1\rangle$, the choice being random with probability $\frac12$ for each. The question might then be about the probability of ending at height $0$ after not dropping below the $x$-axis, but that probability is actually $C_n4^{-n}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I have added a picture above for the Dyck path, which was given.

Comment: It appears that I guessed correctly about the setting: that is exactly the sort of path that I described. There are $C_n$ such paths, and there are altogether $2^{2n}=4^n$ possible paths of length $2n$, so the probability of getting one that ends at $\langle 2n,0\rangle$ and never drops below the $x$-axis should be $C_n4^{-n}$.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I will clarify if this was a typo.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Actually there was a typo. Now I have edited the question. Hope you can help with this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to count the Dyck paths whose **first** return to $0$ occurs after $2n$ steps. The first step must be up, from $\langle 0,0\rangle$ to $\langle 1,1\rangle$, the last step must be down, from $\langle 2n-1,1\rangle$ to $\langle 2n,0\rangle$, and between $\langle 1,1\rangle$ and $\langle 2n-1,1\rangle$ the path must not drop below the line $y=1$. But this means that the path from $\langle 1,1\rangle$ to $\langle 2n-1,1\rangle$ is just a Dyck path from $\langle 0,0\rangle$ to $\langle 2n-2,0\rangle$ that has been translated one unit up and to the right, and there are $C_{n-1}$ such paths. There are altogether $2^{2n}=4^n$ possible paths of length $2n$, all equally probable, so the probability of traversing a Dyck path that begins with an up-step and first returns to height $0$ after $2n$ steps is $C_{n-1}4^{-n}$.

The only way that I see to justify the factor of $2$ in $2C_{n-1}4^{-n}$ is to assume that we also want to include the paths that begin with a down-step and first return to the axis after $2n$ steps. This makes sense if we’re actually talking about a linear random walk along the $y$-axis that is permitted to start in either direction, and we’re using the $x$-axis as a time axis to represent the path of the walk in two dimensions and turn those that we want to count into Dyck paths or the reflections in the $x$-axis of Dyck paths.